# Eval error, Blackberry 5.2, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry

I'm working on a Blackberry 5.2 browser app. I have some JavaScriptthat returns some JSON. I know JSON parsing isn't supported on older Blackberry phones but have been able to use eval to get the job done.

However on the Blackberry Curve running 5.2 my eval statements throw an error. The error is

> SyntaxError: Error in eval(): Expecting ';' found ':' ...

The string that it is trying to parse is correct and clean.

The javascript looks like this...

```
            request.open("POST", url, false);

            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/json");

            request.send(params);
            return eval(request.responseText);
```

and the response that its trying to eval looks like this...

```
{
    "Authenticated": true,
    "StatusCode": "Success",
    "InternalErrorId": null,
    "AuthenticationToken": "PxjcYnjBLN21ZMcWrEzKi9LC3vdXehMVSegEbVz61aca52113",
    "AuthenticationTokenExpiry": "/Date(1340734497405)/",
    "SessionTimeoutMinutes": 240
}
```

Does anyone know what might be going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: We're not mind readers. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or some other way of conveying the exact input and JavaScript to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, more detail is now added.

Comment: Maybe you can include [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) instead of using `eval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `eval` to parse JSON, you need to wrap the JSON in `()`.

```
return eval('('+request.responseText+')');
```

Comment: Nice catch. I often forget this when I'm fiddling around in the browser console. `var x = {}` _(dangit)_ `var x = ({})`

Comment: @MattBall: Stupid block statements.

Comment: Ahhh very simple but that was it! Thank you.